# Extract scalar value from SSE vector

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd

I have a piece of code which does a comparison on array elements if they are > than a value, in SIMD-ish fashion:

```
void sse(uint *dst, size_t N)
{
    const __m128i condition = _mm_set1_epi32(2);

    for (uint i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i]);
        __m128i cmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(v, condition);
        v = _mm_and_si128(v, cmp);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i], v);
    }
}
```

Now, after the comparison, before **anding** elements - `_mm_and_si128`, I want to count elements which passed the condition, i.e.  those set to '1', and store the sum in an int variable. How can I do that in SIMD? For instance, if out of four only two passed the condition, have this int var = 2.

Comment: See also [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132) comparing different ways of doing a horizontal sum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you would keep a vector count throughout the loop and then just sum the elements of the vector when the loop terminates, e.g.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

uint32_t sse(const uint32_t *dst, const size_t N)
{
    const __m128i condition = _mm_set1_epi32(2);
    __m128i vcount = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    uint32_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i]);
        __m128i vcmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(v, condition);
        v = _mm_and_si128(v, vcmp);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i], v);
        vcount = _mm_add_epi32(vcount, vcmp); // accumulate (negative) counts
    }
    // ... sum vcount here and store in count (see below) ...
    return count;
}
```

Note that we are treating each mask element as an int, i.e. 0 or -1, and so we are accumulating a sum which is the negative of the actual sum.

Efficiency of the final `vcount` summation is not normally too important as it is performed only once for the entire loop, so provided `N` is reasonably large it does not matter how many instructions are required (within reason).

There are several ways of handling the final summation, e.g. you can use `_mm_movemask_epi8` (SSE2) to extract a 16 bit mask and work with that, or you can use `_mm_hadd_epi32` (SSSE3) to calculate a horizontal sum on the vector and then extract the sum as a scalar, e.g.

SSE2:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

int16_t mask = _mm_movemask_epi8(vcount);       // extract 16 bit mask
count = !!(mask & 0x0001) +                     // count non-zero 32 bit elements
        !!(mask & 0x0010) + 
        !!(mask & 0x0100) + 
        !!(mask & 0x1000);
```

SSSE3:

```
#include <tmmintrin.h>

vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);        // horizontal sum of 4 elements
vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);
count = - ((_mm_extract_epi16(vcount, 1) << 16) // extract (and negate) sum to
          | _mm_extract_epi16(vcount, 1));      // get total (positive) count
```

SSE4.2:

```
#include <smmintrin.h>

vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);        // horizontal sum of 4 elements
vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);
count = - _mm_extract_epi32(vcount, 0);         // extract (and negate) sum to
                                                // get total (positive) count
```

---

Here is a complete working version with test harness for the SSE4.2 version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

uint32_t sse(const uint32_t *dst, const size_t N)
{
    const __m128i condition = _mm_set1_epi32(2);
    __m128i vcount = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    uint32_t count = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i += 4)
    {
        __m128i v = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i]);
        __m128i vcmp = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(v, condition);
        v = _mm_and_si128(v, vcmp);
        _mm_store_si128((__m128i *)&dst[i], v);
        vcount = _mm_add_epi32(vcount, vcmp); // accumulate (negative) counts
    }

    vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);    // horizontal sum of 4 elements
    vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);
    count = - _mm_extract_epi32(vcount, 0);     // extract (and negate) sum to
                                                // get total (positive) count

    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t a[4] __attribute__ ((aligned(16))) = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    uint32_t count;

    count = sse(a, 4);

    printf("a = %u %u %u %u \n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
    printf("count = %u\n", count);

    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 -msse4 sse_count.c -o sse_count
$ ./sse_count
a = 0 0 3 4 
count = 2
```

Comment: thanks for your detailed response. Why do we have though _hadd two times on the same variable vcount? So the expression 'vcount = _mm_hadd_epi32(vcount, vcount);' appears two times, the same (same args)? 
this code though works only on icc but not on gcc, or am I failing to include the proper header? Currently I have included <tmmintrin.h> and compiling with option -msse4?

Comment: If you read the description of `_mm_hadd_epi32` in the [Intel Instrinsics Guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide) you'll see that it adds adjacent *pairs* of elements, so we need to do it twice to get the sum of all 4 elements.

Comment: this methond is producing very large meaningless number.. as example I tried it with uint arr[] = {1,2,3,4}; uint c = sse2(arr, 4);, but gives a very large number..
For the gcc I get "_mm_extract_epi32’ was not declared in this scope"

Comment: can you also correct the line: 
vcount = _mm_add_epi32(vcount, vcmp); it should be 'v' and not 'vcmp'. It might be useful for other readers in future.

Comment: I've added a complete working version with test harness above which compiles and runs as expected with gcc.

Comment: thats perfect Paul thanks for your very clean explanation. The problem with g++ went away when I added the flag -msse4.1

Comment: The SSSE3 version should just use `movd` (`int _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (__m128i a)`), which is what `_mm_extract_epi32(vcount, 0)` compiles to anyway.  You absolutely don't want the compiler to emit two `pextrw` instructions and shift/OR them together!  Also, see [my answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35270026/224132) for some other ways to do a hsum: more insns but fewer uops, which might be a win esp. with a uop cache.  Compilers can and do transform one hsum idiom to another, though.